# Ansible unable to elevate privilege to enable mode on cisco gears

Tags: ansible, cisco

I am trying to use ansible to do some automate on our cisco devices

playbook

---

```
- name: change config
   hosts: switches
   gather_facts: false

   tasks:
    - name: add an acl
      ios_config:
        lines: 
         - ip access-list standard 7 permit 172.16.1.0 0.0.0.255
```

hosts file

```
[switches]
sw1 ansible_host=172.16.1.1
```

group_vars\switches.yml

---

```
ansible_connection: network_cli
ansible_network_os: ios
ansible_become: yes
ansible_become_method: enable
ansible_ssh_user: *****
ansible_ssh_pass: *****
ansible_become_pass: ******
```

If I just do an ios_command, there are no issues at all, but if I try to use ios_config to change the configuration I will get below error.

```
 [sw1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "unable to elevate privilege to enable mode, at prompt [None] with error: timeout trying to send command: enable"}
```

ssh to the gears

```
3Fb>en
HCC password: 
3Fb#
```

we have a non-default prompt, how to change on ansible to match this and is there any other need to be done to get this fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> [sw1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "unable to elevate privilege to enable mode, at prompt [None] with error: timeout trying to send command: enable"}

Q: "`We have a non-default prompt, how to change on ansible to match this?`"

A: IMHO, it's not related to the prompt. The prompt defaulted to NONE after *_exec_cli_command* had failed with "`error: timeout trying to send command: enable`". See [nxos.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/terminal/nxos.py)

```
    try:
        self._exec_cli_command(to_bytes(json.dumps(cmd), errors='surrogate_or_strict'))
        prompt = self._get_prompt()
        if prompt is None or not prompt.strip().endswith(b'enable#'):
            raise AnsibleConnectionFailure('failed to elevate privilege to enable mode still at prompt [%s]' % prompt)
    except AnsibleConnectionFailure as e:
        prompt = self._get_prompt()
        raise AnsibleConnectionFailure('unable to elevate privilege to enable mode, at prompt [%s] with error: %s' % (prompt, e.message)
```

You might want to start debugging at "`exec_command`" in [connection.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/connection.py)